# jquery .each() value is entire array after ajax return

Tags: jquery, perl, get, each

I'm having a silly problem I think.  I feel stupid, I use each all over the place.  I'm still newbie to Javascript, but I'm coming along.  I pass a 'promotion code id' to a perl script on button click via .get(), I return some 'product ids' and I want to loop through those ids and replace/update a hidden input value.  This seems simple enough but my value on a single iteration is the entire array?

```
$.get('./ajax_get_products.pl', { function_name : 'fix_product_dates', promo_id : selected_promo_id }, function(data) {
                    $.each([data], function(i, value) {
                            $('#products_dates :input[id='+value+']').val(output);
                    });
            });
```

If I do alert(value) inside of each, it displays the entire array.  For testing the current value of [data] = [51, 52, 53].  So, I'm expecting alert(value) to throw me three alerts with a single integer in each alert.  I'm returning this from a Perl script (no choice cause it's for work), is my header coming back from Perl possible wrong? I tried

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: remove the brackets around `[data]` in your `$.each`

Comment: use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of $.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returned data is a string not an array.
You can remove the [] and then split on the comma to convert the data into an array.

However, if you have access to the perl script, return a JSON string, which will be easier to work with.

So return {"1":"51", "2":"52", "3":"53"}

Then you can just use $.parseJSON(data) before you loop through it. And remove the [] around data in your each call.

Comment: Thanks Vlad! Adding data = data.split(','); and removing [] resolved my issue.  I do have access to the Perl script (cause I wrote it hehe), but decided to just add this line.

Comment: @SpongekyleHashpants parsing JSON by hand makes sense almost like using shoes instead of bike brakes.

Comment: @mpapec I believe I agree with you, in this case my return data is not JSON.  I'm just returning integers to update the input id.  I opted not to make the return JSON.  I do however return JSON from ajax calls, depending on the function name passed, all throughout the same pl script for autocomplete.

Comment: @SpongekyleHashpants Since you control the return, just return the CSV data so you can avoid having to remove the []

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an array with the `data` as the only item to `$.each()`, I think what you want is to iterate through the `data` object

```
$.get('./ajax_get_products.pl', {
    function_name: 'fix_product_dates',
    promo_id: selected_promo_id
}, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, value) {
        $('#products_dates :input[id=' + value + ']').val(output);
    });
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Note however that `data` is probably a string.

Comment: @KevinB missed the `Content-Type`, since is an array probably the dataType can be passed as `json` to fix it